Exporting 16 bit depth map image from QGIS
I have USGS 1meter data from OpenTopography. I understand how to rescale the data to fill the range from 0 to 65535 (this is in QGIS). The way I try to export the data is via Raster -> Conversion -> Translate. The gdal command is giving me 8 bit output when I pick png file format:
gdal_translate -of PNG 16bit.tif /home/steve/Desktop/cnc_topo/Altadena/SPzoom2b.png
Older posts similar to my question have answers "edit the gdal command". I am unable to edit it.
How can I get a 16 bit gray scale output?
My goal is to get rid of stair stepping in cnc results.
I am using QGIS 3.22.4 running on Linux Mint 21.3.

PolyGeo seems to want my question to be a statement

You can both set the output data type and add additional command line parameters:

See also gdal_translate problem translating 16bit PNGs, https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rasterconversion.html#translate-convert-format, https://gdal.org/en/latest/programs/gdal_translate.html#gdal-translate
